# Error when enterting this command ALTER TABLE `report` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Tags: mysql

I get an error when using this command to alter my SQL table

Error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;  
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right   
syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE `report` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1, 30' at line 2`
```

Any idea of that?

Comment: Error messages; read them

Comment: Are you possibly trying to execute several queries at once?

Answer (score 5):

So why would you say `AUTO_INCREMENT=1,30`  ?

It has to be one number, and not a comma separated list of numbers.

```
ALTER TABLE report AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE report AUTO_INCREMENT=30
```

Reference: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)